# Preferring non-generic version of method over generic version in c#

Tags: c#, generics, nhibernate, justmock

I'm trying to stub an NHibernate ICriteria using JustMock.

Specifically I'm trying to stub the List<> method when it is called with an array of object:

```
var mockCriteria = Mock.Create<ICriteria>();
Mock.Arrange(() => mockCriteria.List<object[]>()).Returns(
    new object[]
    {
        new object[] {"CompanyX", 1, 1, 1, 0}, 
        new object[] {"CompanyX", 1, 1, 1, 0}, 
        new object[] {"CompanyY", 2, 1, 1, 0}
    });
```

When I execute the second line (the Arrange) I'm getting the error:

```
System.InvalidOperationExceptionSystem.Collections.IList List() is not a GenericMethodDefinition. MakeGenericMethod may only be called on a method for which MethodBase.IsGenericMethodDefinition is true.
   at System.Reflection.RuntimeMethodInfo.MakeGenericMethod(Type[] methodInstantiation)
   at \x7\x5\x2.\x8\x2.\x3\x15\x2(Type \x8, MethodBase , BindingFlags \x1C\xF\x2)   at \x6\x2.\x6\x2.Create(Object , MethodInfo \x6, Boolean \x6\x2)   at \x7\x5\x2.\x11\x14\x2.\x11\x13\x2(\xF\x2 \x5\xF)   at Telerik.JustMock.Mock.\x1F.\x15\x2(\x11\x14\x2 \x2)   at \x7\x5\x2.\x5\x14\x2.\x1C[\x4\x14\x2,\x5\x2](\xF\x2 \xF\x2, Func`2 \x3\x14\x2)   atThreshold.DeviceManagerGateway.UnitTests.Queries.DeviceNetworkStatusQueryFacts.RetrieveDevicesAsDeviceNetworkStats() in DeviceNetworkStatusQueryFacts.cs: line 24
```

`ICriteria` has both a `List()` and a `List<T>()` method and it looks like the compiler is picking up the non-generic version of the `List` method instead of the generic version.  Assuming that I'm correct and that it's picking up the wrong version of the `List` method, does anybody know how to force this?  Or if it's a different problem can anyone point me to how to solve this?

Comment: Out of curiosity, does it work if you rename the method?

Comment: I tried creating a different interface and testing against that (ICriteria is an interface in NHibernate which I can't change): when I created an interface with two identically named methods and tried to mock it the same problem arose.  When I changed the name of one of the methods things started to work.  So, yes changing the name of the method works but I don't have the ability to do that in a third-party library

Comment: I tried it with a recent version of JustMock and the problem doesn't crop up.

Comment: Judging by the presence of obfuscation, it seems that you're using a pretty old version.

Comment: JustMock is version 2013.1.315.0.  Is there a more recent version where this problem is addressed?

Comment: https://www.nuget.org/packages/JustMock/ or from your Telerik account

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I tried it with a recent version of JustMock and the problem doesn't crop up.

Judging by the presence of obfuscation, it seems that you're using a pretty old version.

You can download the latest version of JustMock from [NuGet](https://nuget.org/packages/JustMock) or from your Telerik account.

Comment: Upgrading the version seems to have fixed the problem